# Why is my array separating itself out in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, parameters, colors

So I'm trying to make this smooth color fade transition for my website. I made a function that should do just that, and it even looks like it would work, but I am having a problem I do not understand in the least, nor have I even seen anything like it before. I am using recursion in my function and passing a color I changed back into the function to be changed again. I only exit when the current color matches the target color. What I have COMPLETELY CONFIRMED is happening is that when I pass the 2 arrays back into the function again, they split themselves apart.

Ex: before being passed through, startColsAr=[211, 211, 211].
after being passed through, startColsAr=['2'; '1'; '1'; ','; '2'; '1'; '1'; ','; '2'; '1'; '1'].(semi-colons were used to make reading easier).

As you can see in my function below, nowhere am I doing anything to change the contents of the arrays like that.
Here is my function:

```
function transitionOut(startColAr,endColAr, waitTime, interval, page){      
        //change the colors
        for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
            if(startColAr[i]<endColAr[i]){
                startColAr[i]+=interval;

                if(startColAr[i]>endColAr[i]){startColAr[i]=endColAr[i];}

            }else if(startColAr[i]>endColAr[i]){
                startColAr[i]-=interval;

                if(startColAr[i]<endColAr[i]){startColAr[i]=endColAr[i];}
            }
        }

        //var color="rgb("+startColAr[0]+", "+startColAr[1]+", "+startColAr[2]+")";
        var color = "#"+startColAr[0].toString(16)+startColAr[1].toString(16)+startColAr[2].toString(16);
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;

        if(startColAr[0]==endColAr[0] && startColAr[1]==endColAr[1] && startColAr[2]==endColAr[2]){
            location.href=page;
        }

        window.setTimeout("transitionOut(\'"+startColAr+"\', \'"+endColAr+"\', \'"+delay+"\', \'"+interval+"\', \'"+page+"\')",waitTime);
    }
```

Now, I am only passing in 3 values for both arrays, so I could easily change the 2 arrays to 6 integer parameters(and probably get the function to work(so don't tell me to go download a new library for transitions, THIS IS ABOUT ARRAYS)), but I want to know why this is happening. Does anyone have any suggestions? I have tried a bunch of different things to narrow it down, but I can't seem to put a dent in this at all. A little help?

Comment: Is the final value really a string? ['2'; '1'; '1'; ','; '2'; '1'; '1'; ','; '2'; '1'; '1'] implies that you have a bunch of strings instead of numbers. Nothing in the code you have posted is doing anything like that, so it must be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: It is not, I promise you. All values in the array are NUMBER when they are being passed in a second time. When they start the second "iteration" through the function, they are numbers no more. I think they are chars now, but I haven't checked.

Comment: This code is in a file where this is the ONLY function, btw. I have no external libraries nor JavaScript files that I am reading from. My file, and the function you see, are isolated.

Comment: setTimeout runs [eval](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/efficient-javascript/?page=2#timeouts) when you use quote syntax, which converts arrays to object objects. Use window.setTimeout(function(){transitionOut(startColAr, endColAr,etc...)}, waitTime) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the line:

```
window.setTimeout("transitionOut(\'"+startColAr+"\', \'"+endColAr+"\', \'"+delay+"\', \'"+interval+"\', \'"+page+"\')",waitTime);
```

You are converting your arrays into strings when you are preparing the code to be run later. As per [the Mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout), it would probably be easier to use the alternate form of the setTimeout function:

```
window.setTimeout(transitionOut, waitTime, startColAr, endColAr, waitTime, interval, page);
```

Comment: I realized I had an error with that code I posted. On the recursion call, I had "delay" being passed back, but "delay" isn't specified anymore(i changed names around). That's why it was "error"-ing out. I changed that to waitTime, and it decided it wanted to work that time. It is fully functioning. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is your problem

```
window.setTimeout("transitionOut(\'"+startColAr+"\', \'"+endColAr+"\', \'"+delay+"\', \'"+interval+"\', \'"+page+"\')",waitTime);
```

You probably want something like

```
window.setTimeout(transitionOut, waitTime, startColAr, endColAr, waitTime, interval,page,waitTime);
```

You can call setTimeout with a string literal but I don't think it's recommended.

Comment: I tried doing this first I think, upon trying again, it only lets me run through the function once(it gets an error from that line and sort of closes itself). I tried adding an anonymous function to the window.setTimeout but it also gives me an error on that line. When I say error I mean the function just sort of shuts down and doesn't do anything I put after that line.